# Case_insensitive not working on wildcard field type with cyrilic data

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard, case-insensitive, cyrillic

When you have an index with field that its type is wildcard and its filled with Cyrillic data and then when you perform wildcard query with **case_insensitive: true**, no documents are found.

Note: this is currently on ES version 7.17.8

Test example:

```
PUT /index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "wildcard"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /index/_doc/1
{
  "name": "ТЕСТ"
}

POST /index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name": {
              "value": "*Тест*",
              "case_insensitive": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to search for a fix but could not find anything. Is there anything that can help to solve this issue?

NOTE:
Index data and query data are all the Cyrillic characters.

Cyrilic:

ТЕСТ - `0xd0a2d095d0a1d0a2`

Тест - `0xd0a2d0b5d181d182`

While latin would be:

TECT - `0x54454354`

Tect - `0x54656374`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** if you use an [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) you don't need to add wildcard "*" when you are searching.

```
PUT /test_ngram_analyzer
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      }
    },
    "index.max_ngram_diff": 10
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "test": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /test_ngram_analyzer/_doc/1
{
  "test": "ТЕСТ"
}
POST /test_ngram_analyzer/_doc/2
{
  "test": "TECT"
}

POST /test_ngram_analyzer/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "test": "Тес"
    }
  }
}
```

#if you use ngram analyzer you don't need to add wildcard "*" when you are searching.

#To understand how it works you can use `analyze` aPI

```
POST test_ngram_analyzer/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer", 
  "text" : ["TECT", "ТЕСТ"]
}
```

There is a problem with your lowercase "T" :).

`Тест` => `tect`

```
POST /test_index_musab/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "name": {
              "value": "Tect",
              "case_insensitive": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/keyword.html#wildcard-field-type

Some notes for further information:

**Limitations**

> wildcard fields are untokenized like keyword fields, so do not support
> queries that rely on word positions such as phrase queries. When
> running wildcard queries any rewrite parameter is ignored. The scoring
> is always a constant score.

Comment: Not exactly because all of the characters are actually Cyrillic therefore they are different bytes.

Cyrilic:
ТЕСТ - 0xd0 0xa2 0xd0 0x95 0xd0 0xa1 0xd0 0xa2
Тест - 0xd0 0xa2 0xd0 0xb5 0xd1 0x81 0xd1 0x82

While latin is:
TECT - 0x54 0x45 0x43 0x54
Tect - 0x54 0x65 0x63 0x74

Comment: With wildcard field type it's not possible to tokenize texts. I recommend you use the `ngram` tokenizer with a lowercase tokenizer.